# Opera bookmarks wandering on page

Tags: bookmarks, opera

How do I put the Opera bookmarks back where they belong? Somehow my bookmarks are stuck below my address bar - idiotic place to put them - and I can't get them back where they belong.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific, do you mean the personal bar? You might find more help on the Opera forums: http://my.opera.com/community/forums/tgr.dml?id=2

Answer (score 0):

The Opera feature you're describing is called the start bar. If it got stuck floating in front of the page you will have to restart the browser. Otherwise I believe you are judging hastily: after all where would you need your bookmarks and history?  -Near the address bar seems non-idiotic to me. I grant the option should be readily accessible from Menu > Toolbars.

You can customize your choice of bar in Menu > Appearence (Shift+F12) > Toolbars tab. You might want to check Show hidden toolbar while customizing. There you will also find the regular bookmark bar. Accessing yours bookmarks from a side "Panel" is yet another possibility. Then again there's the Speed dial for you to tweak. I hope you find a configuration that makes sense to you...

Edit :: !o! - I was forgetting the regular bookmark menu from the regular menu bar... (Menu > Show menu bar)